# Best way to handle element of dict that has multiple key/value pairs inside it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parsing

```
[{'id': 2, 'Registered Address': 'Line 1: 1 Any Street Line 2: Any locale City: Any City Region / State: Any Region Postcode / Zip code: BA2 2SA Country: GB Jurisdiction: Any Jurisdiction'}]
```

I have the above read into a dataframe and that is the output so far. The issue is I need to break out the individual elements - due to names of places etc the values may or may not have spaces in them - looking at the above my keys are Line 1, Line 2, City, Region / State, Postcode / Zip, Country, Jurisdiction.

Output required for the "Registered Address"-'key'is the keys and values

```
"Line 1": "1 Any Street"
"Line 2": "Any locale"
"City": "Any City"
"Region / State": "Any Region"
"Postcode / Zip code": "BA2 2SA"
"Country": "GB"
"Jurisdiction": "Any Jurisdiction"
```

Just struggling to find a way to get to the end result.I have tried to pop out and use urllib.prse but fell short - is anypone able to point me in the best direction please?

Comment: Are your keys other than these? or they'll be the same for other enteries?

Comment: For this part of the dataframe it will be the same keys - however the csv that is read in has one key one value on other fields I can handle them fine its just this one field with many keys / values but again as your question yes it will alays be this key / value combination in the adress field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried to write a code that generalizes your question, but there were some limitations, regarding your data format. Anyway I would do this:

```
def address_spliter(my_data, my_keys):
    address_data = my_data[0]['Registered Address']
    key_address = {}
    for i,k in enumerate(keys):
        print(k)
        if k == 'Jurisdiction:':
            key_address[k] = address_data.split('Jurisdiction:')[1].removeprefix(' ').removesuffix(' ')
        else:
            key_address[k] = address_data.split(k)[1].split(keys[i+1])[0].removeprefix(' ').removesuffix(' ')
    return key_address
```

were you can call this function like this:

```
my_data = [{'id': 2, 'Registered Address': 'Line 1: 1 Any Street Line 2: Any locale City: Any City Region / State: Any Region Postcode / Zip code: BA2 2SA Country: GB Jurisdiction: Any Jurisdiction'}]
```

and

```
my_keys = ['Line 1:','Line 2:','City:', 'Region / State:',  'Postcode / Zip code:', 'Country:', 'Jurisdiction']
```

As you can see It'll work if only the sequence of keys is not changed. But anyway, you can work around this idea and change it base on your problem accordingly if it doesn't go as expected.

Comment: Masoud - thanks I'll give this a go later today and report back - many thanks for your time its genuinely appreciated and I'll upvote answer once tested :-)